# How should canonical and alternate links be handled for color variants of products between separate desktop and mobile URLs?

Tags: seo, mobile, rel-canonical, products

Working on a large scale eCommerce site (15,000+ products), with separate URLs for Mobile & Desktop.

On desktop product pages, we have canonicals set up for color variations, so `/product/green/`, `/product/red/`, `/product/blue/` are all canonicalized to `/product/white/`.

At the same time, we have `rel=alternate` on every desktop page to indicate the mobile version.

My question is, how should I handle mobile canonicals for color variations (canonicalized on desktop)? Does the following example scenario represent a problem for indexation?

On desktop (`https://www.example.com/product/blue/`)

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/product/white/" /><link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://www.example.com/mobile/product/blue/" />`

On mobile (`https://www.example.com/mobile/product/blue/`)

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/product/blue/" />`

Is it a problem that the mobile URL is canonicalized to a URL that is not a true canonical? Should it point to `https://www.example.com/product/white/` instead?

Responsive website coming soon, but until then...stuck with these 2 sites

Comment: Note: the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.